# How do I handle raising an error if reqwest status code is not 200

Tags: rust, reqwest

I am still learning rust but having a little hard time understanding how to raise an error. I am trying to consume an API but if something goes wrong (example: the api key is wrong so I get a forbidden) how do I handle this? At the moment since a response was received (even if it was forbidden) there is no error (which makes sense) - how do I trigger an error after inspecting the code? I've been trying:

```
async fn make_api_call(endpoint: &str) -> Result<Response, Error> {
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();
    dotenv().ok();
    let os_request_url = std::env::var("OS_REQUEST_URL").expect("os_request_url must be set.");
    let os_api_key = std::env::var("OS_API_KEY").expect("os_api_key must be set.");

    let client_response = client
        .get(format!("{os_request_url}{endpoint}"))
        .header("X-Api-Key", "os_api_key")
        .header(ACCEPT, "application/json")
        .send()
        .await?;

    let status_code = client_response.status().as_u16();

    Ok(client_response)
}
```

I have tried to create my own custom error type but that seems verbose and I'm not sure how I raise this error. The goal would be to handle the error based on the status_code:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct APIError {
    status_code: u16,
    details: String,
}

trait StatusCodeTrait: Debug {
    fn status_code(&self) -> &u16;
}

impl StatusCodeTrait for APIError {
    fn status_code(&self) -> &u16 {
        &self.status_code
    }
}

impl Error for APIError {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        &self.details
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for APIError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "API Error")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please just read the documentation for the crates you're using. Reqwest's `Response` type literally has a method [`Response::error_for_status`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.error_for_status).

If you haven't already, I also suggest you read "The Book", especially the chapter on [error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html). It will give you all you need to know on how to write custom error types and combine them with those from libraries.